# Delete N rows from Datatable without using iteration

Tags: c#, datatable, rowdeleting

I am using a set of DataTables to store values continuously, from which I have to delete n number of  rows.

My problem is,

- when the number of rows reach a limit i have to delete n rows.
- Deletion should not affect the other writing processes in the Datatable.

Please help me to solve this problem /or give suggestions

**Edit from heading**

I want to use a method which doesn't have an iteration in it.

Comment: are the rows which you want to delete a range? or are there gaps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8225055/169714

Comment: Yes a range of every 1000 records

Comment: Why don't you use something like this: `delete from Table where id between 1000 and 2000`

Comment: Thanks for you reply . Actually the datatable is not from database it is a C# datatable

Comment: So it is a `List<T>` of objects? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No it is not a list. I get value from a callback event and store it in a temporary table and after reaching n records , i insert n records to database and want to delete the first  n records from the datatable , so that the values retrieved from callback event after n rows will not be deleted

Comment: So you are looking for a persistent queue pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29

Comment: Give some  primary key for the table, then U can delete the rows with in range using P'key

Comment: You need to delete the records that have been inserted to database right? You will have a method call to update database from datatable. In the same method delete each row after updating in database.

Comment: @Rockstart Thanks for your comment. But I am not follow the row by row insertion. I copy first n records to an xml file and then insert into the database table by a single Load xml query. Actually i want to remove the n records from the datatable without using iteration.